# Will I ever be offered a Governor position by a non-English Governor?

Tags: port-royale-gold-power-and-pirates

I have played the game as a Dutch merchant. My victory was “Become a Governor”. But as I have reached the end of the game, I was offered the governor position by every **English** governor, although I am Dutch.

Is that normal? Will I always be offered that position by the English no matter what my nation is?